# Reading through different excel sheets to plot

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to read through multiple sheets within same excel file. I want to plot specific columns for every sheet on same figure but it says that `'Excelfile' has no attribute 'iloc'.` Can someone tell me what is wrong here? thank you

```
df = pd.ExcelFile ('Current parametric sweep_reference.xlsx')

Sheet=df.sheet_names

print(Sheet)

for sheet_names in Sheet:
    
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:,1],iloc[:,9])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the data-frame but the sheet-names. You can do the following

```py
dfs = pd.ExcelFile ('Current parametric sweep_reference.xlsx')

for sheet in df.sheet_names: #loop over all sheets
    df = pd.read_excel("Current parametric sweep_reference.xlsx",sheet_name=sheet)
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:,1],df.iloc[:,9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object `df` is not a pandas DataFrame but an ExcelFile object, which does not support `iloc`. To use `iloc` you should first represent the individual sheets as DataFrames, like so:

```
... 
for sheet_name in Sheet:
    sheet_df = df.parse(sheet_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [´pd.read_excel´](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for loading your excel file. By providing ´sheet=None´ to ´pd.read_excel´ you load all sheets into a dictionary of dataframes per sheet. Then you can iterate over the sheets as following:

```
import pandas as pd

sheets = pd.read_excel("'Current parametric sweep_reference.xlsx'", sheet_name=None)
for sheetname, df in sheets.items():
    plt.plot(df.iloc[:,1],df.iloc[:,9])
```